# Clarification about this Caja( secure JavaScript ) code?

Tags: javascript, code-analysis, google-caja

I am studying Caja and having some trouble understanding how it works:

```
function Brand() {
  var flag = false, payload = null; 

  return caja.freeze({
    seal: function(payloadToSeal) {
      function box() {
        flag = true;
        payload = payloadToSeal;
      }
      box.toString = function() {
        return "(box)";
      };
      unseal: function(box) {
        flag = false;
        payload = null; 
        try {
          box();
          if (!flag)  { throw ...; }
          return payload;
        } finally {
          flag = false;
          payload = null; 
        }
      }
   });
}
```

This has a caption that reads:

> Fig. 10: Rights amplification. Each brand has a seal and unseal
>   function, acting like a matched encryption and decryption key. Sealing
>   an object returns a sealed box that can only be unsealed by the
>   corresponding unseal function. The implementation technique shown here
>   is due to M. Stiegler.

Is this pseudocode? I'm confused at what's happening, such as at `box()` and `throw ...;` . I appreciate any tips or advice.

[Here is the Specification PDF where I got this.](http://google-caja.googlecode.com/files/caja-spec-2008-06-07.pdf)

Comment: The `throw ...` line is pseudocode; the rest looks real.

Comment: Thanks a lot apsillers! It is getting a bit clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `throw` bit is pseudocode.  The real code is available via [svn](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/Brand-cajita.js).

Marc Stiegler describes the sealer/unsealer pattern and other secure decomposition patterns at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eL5o4PFuxTY